# Derivative problem with second derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can you give me a hint on how to solve this problem:
If function f and g has a second derivative on interval (a,b). Let $ f''(x)+p(x)f(x)=0$ and $ g''(x)+p(x)g(x)=0$, $p(x)$ is an arbitrary function on interval (a,b). 
a) Prove that $F(x)=f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)$ is equal to a constant. (I proved this one)
but with part b) I am stuck it says:
Prove, if $F(x)$ is non zero, and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ for $a<x_1<x_2<b$, then g(c)=0 for some c in interval (a,b).
Can I apply Lagrange theorem somehow? I tried to study $(f/g)$ function to no avail.

Comment: The same equality is written twice. Should the second one have g not f?

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you for correcting me! I'll edit that.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there exist $x_1 < x_2$ in $(a,b)$ such that etc.?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Assume $f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)=k\ne 0.$ Since $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ we get that

$$f'(x_1)g(x_1)=f'(x_2)g(x_2)=k.$$

Now, it is possible to have $\operatorname{sign}(f'(x_1))= \operatorname{sign}(f'(x_2)).$ But since $f$ is not identically zero (in other case, $k=0$),

- Can you construct an interval $[x_1,x_3]$ such that $[x_1,x_3]\subseteq [x_1,x_2]$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_3)=0$ and $\operatorname{sign}(f'(x_1))\ne \operatorname{sign}(f'(x_2))?$
- If yes, you have $\operatorname{sign}(g(x_1))\ne \operatorname{sign}(g(x_2)).$ Is Bolzano helpful now?

Comment: my edit was simply formatting $sign$ to`\operatorname{sign}`= $\operatorname{sign}$